# -pipelinevariable and blocking commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3

“Some blocking commands collect all the pipeline items before producing any output, for example Sort-Object or Select-Object -Last. Any PipelineVariable assigned in a command before such a blocking command always contains the final piped item from the preceding command when used in a command after the blocking command.”

I’m piping an array of AzureADUser objects to Get-EXOMailboxStatistics and it works. But the later is breaking the pipeline. I’m trying to do format-table and use the variable from -pipelinevariable to add a property to the mailboxstat. But it brings the last element. I’m suspecting because it’s blocking and that screws up the element.
I can work around this with a foreach loop, but that slows it down by 20+ times. Is there a way to avoid that?

Thanks

```
echo $azureadusers -pipelinevariable user | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -Properties LastInteractionTime,LastUserActionTime,lastlogontime | format-table @{
     name='UPN’; expression={$user.UserPrincipalName}}, displayname, LastUserActionTime
```

Comment: This is very likely as you stated, `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics` is consuming all input before outputting hence `$user` references the last element from `$azureadusers`.

Comment: Yes, but how can I work around this, short of running the EXO command in a foreach loop, which slows it down by 20 times?

Comment: Only workaround you have is to enumerate `$azureadusers`.

Comment: How? With a foreach loop?

Comment: or a `ForEach-Object` yes

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics` but by what you have already stated in your question, it is consuming all input from the pipeline before outputting hence `$user` becomes the last element in `$azureadusers`. In other words, `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics` is not a streaming cmdlet.

A way to see what this means is by comparing a streaming cmdlet such as `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-Process -PipelineVariable proc | ForEach-Object { $_ } |
    Format-Table @{ N='Name'; E={ $proc.ProcessName }}
```

With a cmdlet that consumes all input before outputting such as `Sort-Object`:

```
Get-Process -PipelineVariable proc | Sort-Object ProcessName |
    Format-Table @{ N='Name'; E={ $proc.ProcessName }}
```

The workaround in your case is to use a loop of your choice, `Foreach-Object` in this case:

```
$azureadusers | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_
    $user | Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -PropertySets All |
        Select-Object @{ N='UPN'; E={ $user.userprinciplename }}, displayname, LastUserActionTime
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: I’m wondering if there’s some hack where you can append the objectID to the final pscustomobject internally? Either by modifying the internals of the EXO command or some other wizardry. Once the objectID is there, I can match the azure objects to the exchange objects

Comment: @user242114 I'm not sure there is, I would instead figure output if there isnt a more efficient cmdlet than `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics` or if there is a specific need to use `-PropertySets All` instead of `-PropertySets Minimum`

Comment: My real command only had the properties I needed, it wasn't "All"

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue as OP, switched to using Get-Mailboxstatistics instead, with that the pipline variable iterates.

```
echo $azureadusers -pipelinevariable user | Get-MailboxStatistics | format-table @{
     name='UPN’; expression={$user.userprinciplename}}, displayname, LastUserActionTime
```

Comment: How much does that slow down? Isn’t that?